# Twilio REST API (via Python SDK) Time Limit on Calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am aware of the 4 hour limit on `<Twiml/>` initiated `<Dial/>`'s.  However, I need to make a call that sometimes requires being on hold for long periods.

I've noticing that the REST API (via Python SDK) seems to time out at consistently the same amount of time 1 Hr 35 Mins 36 Secs.

Is there anyway to extend the REST API call create to be 4 hours, or to refresh the limit manually somehow after a certain period?

Comment: This doesn't make sense (can't see how one is related to the other), `I've noticing that the REST API (via Python SDK) seems to time out at consistently the same amount of time 1 Hr 35 Mins 36 Secs.`. Can you clarify what you are attempting to do? Without any API calls, the call will last for a maximum of 4 hours.

Comment: TWIML gives you 4 hours.  API calls don't seem to give a max timeout of 4 hours.  That's how they're related.  Maybe my English isn't very good.

Comment: API calls get cut-off at precisely 1h and 35 min and 36 sec each and every time if it's left that long.  I'm wondering how to make sure API calls also last 4 hours without ending prematurely.  I think you might know something about ending prematurely?